# Firebase await error: Some requested document was not found

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

```
async function confirmCode() {
try {
  data = await confirm.confirm(code);
  if(data.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser){
     await firestore.collection("Users").doc(auth.currentUser.uid).update({
      id:auth.currentUser.uid,
    })
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
//Error: [firestore/not-found] Some requested document was not found.
```

When I use this code to create user & also make firestore data of user it returns error.
But if user is already created, this returns wonderful result.
Any helps can I get to successfully create firestore data when new user comes?

Comment: 1/ Are you sure `auth.currentUser.uid` is not null (see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)) and 2/ Why don't you await the `update()` asynchronous operation?

Comment: 1. auth.currentUser.uid returns the non null value.
2. how can i await the update()?

Comment: I have changed my code

Comment: #2: just with `await firestore.collection("Users").doc(auth.currentUser.uid).update();`

Comment: Ok, I see the code change. For #1, you should double check  that `auth.currentUser.uid` is not null. As explained in the link I mentioned above (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), the Auth object can  be in an intermediate state—such as initialization—.  I don't see from where else the following error could come: `Error: [firestore/not-found] Some requested document was not found`...

Comment: I found the reason why this problem happened.
.update() made an error because collection("Users").doc(auth.currentUser.uid) didn't exists!
Thanks a lot for your help it gave me inspiration

Comment: Glad I could help you! I therefore propose to write an answer along those lines that you would upvote and accept ;-) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message `//Error: [firestore/not-found] Some requested document was not found.` is seems that you have a problem with the Firestore document you try to update with `await firestore.collection("Users").doc(auth.currentUser.uid).update();`

One classical problem when using `auth.currentUser` is that it is possible that the `Auth` object is not fully initialized and that `auth.currentUser.uid` is therefore null. As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) you should either use the `onAuthStateChanged()` observer or check that `auth.currentUser` is not null.

It may also happen that the document is not existing for another reason (e.g. you never created it!): since you are calling `update()` the document must exist, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update): "The update will fail if applied to a document that does not exist.".